# Canvas JS issue with Angular5

Tags: javascript, charts, angular5, canvasjs

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as CanvasJS from 'canvasjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-js',
  templateUrl: './canvas-js.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-js.component.scss']
})
export class CanvasJsComponent implements OnInit {
canvasChartData: any;
  canvasChartDataCopy: number[];
  canvasChart: any;
  canvasChartContext: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  let dataPoints = [];
 let y = 0;  
 for ( var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {    
  y += Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5)); 
  dataPoints.push({ y: y});
 }
 let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("canvasjsContainer", {
  zoomEnabled: true,
   animationEnabled: true,
  exportEnabled: true,
  title: {
   text: "Performance Demo - 10000 DataPoints"
  },
  subtitles:[{
   text: "Try Zooming and Panning"
  }],
  data: [
  {
   type: "line",                
   dataPoints: dataPoints
  }]
 });
  
 chart.render();
}
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasjsContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 80%; margin: 10%;"></div>
```

I tried the sample given in official website of Canvas JS with Angular5. Tried with npm install. But on build of angular application, giving build error as:
| export ColumnChart from '../charts/column';
| export StackedColumnChart from '../charts/stacked_column';

Not getting how to solve this issue. Using v1.8.0 of Canvas JS.

Answer (score 4):

CanvasJS doesn’t have official npm package published yet. The package that you are using through npm is not an official one but from a third party.

You can save CanvasJS library (canvasjs.min.js) in source folder of your project (‘src/app’ or ‘src/app/assets/js’ or ‘src/app/lib’) and import it to your app using import * as CanvasJS from './canvasjs.min' (path may vary based on file location like ‘./assets/js/canvasjs.min’ or ‘./lib/canvasjs.min’).

Here is a [sample project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am6ZJqYg9ZmfgX84mizXtJijjzuS)  showing how to import CanvasJS Charts in your Angular 5 App.

Comment: ...Thanks a lot for your help.